# Is it possibile to count the distinct events (by id), using Kafka Stream?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I must to count the distinct Events, into time interval. I 've the events related to vehicles. Each event has a idVehicle. How can I count the distinct events, by idVehicle, into time interval, using KafkaStream DSL (Spring boot)?

Comment: What did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`idVehicle` has to be the key of the stream. You have to [group the stream by key](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations), apply [windowing](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing) on top of the grouped stream and use [`count()` aggregation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating).

```
stream
   .groupByKey()
   .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
   .count();
```

The result will be a table with key type `Windowed<T>` (where `T` is the type of your id) and value type `Long`, which contains the count.